# How to connect to mysql docker instance using localhost over network bridge?

Tags: mysql, docker

I am running MySQL via docker-compose and trying to connect to it from the host, not another container, via a JDBC connection string for an app running on the host and not in a container. The environment is locked down, I cannot create new docker networks or bind a container to 'host' network, bridge is the only option. I can connect to the MySQL instance using the IP address of the container, but this is not much use - I need to use `localhost` or  `127.0.0.1`. Is this possible? If so, how?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  db:
    container_name: mysql_db
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'test-db'
      MYSQL_USER: 'test-user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
volumes:
  my-db:
```

I can connect using the container's IP, like so:

```
 jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.3:3306/test-db
```

But cannot connect using `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` or the container name `mysql_db` like so:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test-db
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test-db
jdbc:mysql://mysql_db:3306/test-db
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean. By usins `docker run`, you are trying to connect from another container, not from the host.

Comment: You can just use `mysql` from the host; you don't need to `sudo docker run` a container to be the client.  (If you do `docker run` a container, both containers need to be on the same Docker network and you need to use the other container's name, not `localhost`; see for example [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation for some more details.)

Comment: @Genu I have edited the question to make the usage clear - I need to connect using a JDBC string from the host, not from another container.

Comment: @DavidMaze clarified the usage - I am not connecting from another container so using the mysql db container name doesn't work.

Comment: Explicitly using `127.0.0.1` (or the host system's DNS name) should work.  The MySQL client unfortunately misinterprets `localhost` to mean "use a Unix socket" rather than a host name.

Comment: The clarifications make me think you are still trying to access your database from another container. Can you tell us where this `jdbc:mysql:` configuration came from?

Comment: @Genu I am not connecting from another container - I have an app, running locally, running some tests, that needs to connect to the MySql instance. It works with a hardcoded IP address. How can I connect using `localhost`?

Comment: @jimmy_terra sorry, but there's something missing about your context. If I try on my side, it works fine (with network_mode bridge and mysq:5.7 image). I can connect to MySQL using localhost or 127.0.0.1, as expected. Please try to connect from your IDE or a MySQL client.

Comment: @Genu interesting, I definitely cannot. How are you connecting to your MySQL container?

Comment: @jimmy_terra I used a jdbc connection in the database client component of my IDE. But I used a more recent version of compose file (version 3.3).

Answer (score 0):

Since `127.0.0.1` and  `localhost` means the `host` your `docker` is currently running, so you cannot connect to your host's `mysql`.

I also recommend connect container using `hostname`:

```
docker run -it --network bridge --rm mysql mysql -hmysql_db -utest-user –ppassword
```

Comment: I have edited the question to make the usage clearer. I need to connect from an app running on the host, not from another container, over jdbc. Please see the updated question.

Comment: You need to create a network and add these two containers into that network. You may either add them in one `docker-compose` with `network` keyword, or run these two separately but add them into one network. I don't know how the other app is running (docker-compose or docker run). See networking of docker and if you did not understand what to do, comment here so I edit my answer respectively.

Comment: I can't create a network, the environment is locked down. I can only use Bridge.